# AWS Lambda CodePipeline can't fine my deps.json file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to build & deploy a simple sample project to learn AWS. C# / .NET Core.

My buildspec looks like this:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      dotnet: 2.2
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Restore started on `date`
      - dotnet restore AWSServerless1.csproj
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - dotnet publish -c release -o ./build_output AWSServerless1.csproj
artifacts:
  files:
    - ./build_output/**/*
    - scripts/**/*
    - appspec.yml
  discard-paths: yes
```

My appspec looks like this:

```
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - myStack-AspNetCoreFunction-1HPKUEU7I6GFW:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
      Properties:
        Name: "myStack-AspNetCoreFunction-1HPKUEU7I6GFW"
        Alias: "AWSServerless1"
        CurrentVersion: "1"
        TargetVersion: "2"
```

The pipeline completes successfully, but when I try to run the lambda, I get a 502. I checked the logs and it says:

```
Could not find the required 'AWSServerless1.deps.json'. This file should be present at the root of the deployment package.: LambdaException
```

When I download the package from S3, to me, it looks like everything is there. It's a zip file, no paths anywhere, everything is in the root of the zip including AWSServerless1.deps.json.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use dotnet lambda package instead of publish

see https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli